# Who is in the painting behind Mycroft's desk in "The Empty Hearse"?

Tags: sherlock, props

In the scene where Sherlock is talking to Mycroft after his extraction from Serbia, they are in a dark office. My presumption is that this would some kind of office belonging to Mycroft, and not necessarily one he commandeered. Although we don't see the office before season three, the presence of the painting in the scene (amidst the general darkness) is somewhat focal and pronounced.

Who is the person that is the subject of the painting, and is it an otherwise historical painting? If it is not a specific individual, is there a resource that helps (non-British) viewers better understand the various iconography and artwork frequently accompanying scenes with Mycroft?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Painting from the show]

Comment: A picture might help...

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and say a picture **would** help. Or a time-code to not watch the entire episode and be chagrined when someone beat you to it... I have to leave in five minutes, so this comment isn't even for me.

Comment: I would assume a picture would violate copyright law. However, watching on Netflix, the top half is visible but blurry in the 0:14:02 segment of the scene (the bottom half is in better focus in the 0:12:10 segment).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you talking about [Pietro Annigoni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pietro_Annigoni)'s portrait of [Queen Elizabeth II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Elizabeth_II)? Here it is:

[image]

It's actually visible quite clearly in other parts of the episode.

Comment: Now the question arises given his stature and importance, does Mycroft own the original? It's just a joke, I know it's not mentioned in the show. (He probably **totally** owns the original, though.)